# Angular 2 Dynamic <head> Javascript and CSS Libraries

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to find a method for swapping out css and js libraries depending on the route selected...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

   ->if homepage load homepage requirements...
   ->if admin load admin requirements...

</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I know there is a way to do this with web pack but can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question specifically regarding Webpack, I don't think Webpack can help you here. Webpack is a build tool that generates files for distribution. To do what you want, you need to make a decision based on the route which is a runtime variable, this is long after Webpack has finished its work. There are other solutions though.

One solution is to use vanilla javascript.

```
<head>
    ...
    <script>
         var script = document.createElement('script');
         script.type = 'text/javascript';
         // Implement resource decision logic here however
         script.src = location.href.includes('admin') ? "//site.com/admin-resource.js" : "//site.com/home-resource.js"

         $("#body").append(script);
    </script>
</head>
```

You could do this for both js and css.

Another solution is to dynamically generate the links at the server, based on the route, when the page is requested. But I don't think that will work for you because from what I can tell you want to change these resources based on the routes from inside your angular spa app.

Please note, I don't really recommend all this. If you have javascript and even more so for css files that are so large you can't load them at once...you probably have some structural issues else where. You might think of splitting your app into two modules (an admin module and a main module) and then place the links to the resources in the respective top level app.component.html files.